# Remote Server Appender for Logback

Tags: java, log4j, logback

How can I configure logback to send log messages to a remote server appender?

For example, in log4j I can have something like below in the log4j property file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=server
# Redirect logs
log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=3501
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=30000
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it,

```
<configuration>

      <appender name="SOCKET" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
        <remoteHost>${host}</remoteHost>
        <port>${port}</port>
        <reconnectionDelay>10000</reconnectionDelay>
        <includeCallerData>${includeCallerData}</includeCallerData>
      </appender>

      <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="SOCKET" />
      </root>  

</configuration>
```